# Responsive Web Design Tools

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

i'm developing a website and now i have to otimize him for tables, smart phones, etc...
I already found some tools to test the css media queries like responsinator, and for some things it's good, but it looks not for everything like some tests on real smart phones told me.
However, since i don't have much oportunities to test the website on real devices, anyone here could tell me some websites where i can do this tests? Websites you people have already used and were satisfied with them?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

If you install the [web developer toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) addon on Firefox you can take a look at the "resize" menu

[image]

and select the last item "view responsive layout". A new page will appear with the following mobile/small device resolutions

- 320x480
- 600x800
- 1024x768

both in portrait and landscape orientation. Of course this can't be an effective alternative to "real testing", but it could be used for a first check to solve main issues.

Answer (score 4):

[Opera Mobile Emulator](http://www.opera.com/developer/tools/mobile/).

[Opera Mini Simulator](http://www.opera.com/developer/tools/mini/).

[Android Emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html).

[Blackberry Simulators](https://swdownloads.blackberry.com/Downloads/entry.do?code=060AD92489947D410D897474079C1477)

Also the Override User Agent option in Chrome Developer Tools.

[image]

And a lot more [mobile emulators and simulators](http://www.mobilexweb.com/emulators).

Comment: What about the iphones that use safari as navigator, testing with this tools will work?

Comment: I'm thinking it should work. Then again, I've never touched an iPhone in my life, let alone check how it displays a site compared to a desktop previewer.